# Navigate through the frame context using JavaScript in Chrome or Firefox Console [Without Manually using the Drop down List]

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, frame, google-chrome-console

I am trying to extract some data from a webpage where I don't want to use Selenium.
So I am using JavaScript in the chrome console, but I am facing the below problem while accessing the iframe.

**blocked a frame with origin "example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.**

I understand the cross-origin issue and have tried multiple things mentioned in other answers but nothing seem to work. The only solution I could think of is programmatically selecting the Frame context otherwise which could be done manually as shown below in the image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1wu5.png)

Could someone help if there is a way to change this programmatically!

These are somethings I tried

document.querySelector("iframe").contentWindow.document.querySelector(".class name")

var frame = document.querySelector("iframe").contentWindow;
cd(frame)